# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'user_login' not found. 'user_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, html, django

New to Django 2. I have checked all the earlier post related to this error but could not find my mistake. Below are the details :
Project - learning_users ; App - basic_app. There are 4 templates - base.html, index.html, login.html, registration. html.

**views.py**

```
from basic_app.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Views

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'basic_app/index.html')

@login_required
def special(request):
    return HttpResponse("You are logged in, Nice !")

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid and profile_form.is_valid:
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
            profile.save()
            registered = True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request, 'basic_app/registration.html',
            {'user_form':user_form,
             'profile_form':profile_form,
            'registered':registered})

def user_login(request):
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else :
                return HttpResponse('User Not Active')

        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed")
            print("Username : {}, password : {}".format(username, password)) 
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Login Details")
    else:
        return render(request, 'basic_app/login.html', {})
```

**app level urls.py**

```
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
       path('register/', views.register, name='register'), 
       path('user_login/', views.user_login, name='login')
```

**project level urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from basic_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name ='index'),
    path('basic_app', include('basic_app.urls')),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    path('special/', views.special, name='special'),
]
```

**base.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class='container'>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Django</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'basic_app:register' %}">Registration</a></li>

                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout Successful</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}">Login</a></li>   
                {% endif %}    
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class='container'>
    {% block body_block %}

    {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'basic_app/base_html' %}

{% block body_block %}

<div class='jumbotron'>
    <h1>Please login</h1>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'user_login' %}" >
        
    {% csrf_token %}
        
        <label for="username">Username :</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">

        <label for="password">Password :</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">

        <input type="submit" value="Login">

    </form>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I get the following error (I am unable to embed the screenshot):

Error During Template Rendering
In template /media/danny/My Passport/Python/Course - Django/Django_level_five/learning_users/templates/basic_app/base.html, error at line 22
Reverse for 'user_login' not found. 'user_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

[No ReverseMatch error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DTbC.png)

Can someone please help me here ? Have done a lot of checking and research but unable to pinpoint error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `login.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'basic_app:login' %}" >
```

And in your `base.html`:

```
<li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'basic_app:login' %}">Login</a></li>
```

As, your name is: `login` in your `urls.py`:

```
path('user_login/', views.user_login, name='login')
```